# Rewrite / extend product type in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to overwrite a function from `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable`. But I don't want to break my code on updates so I wanted to write a small module for it.

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_SaleableIndex>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_SaleableIndex>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_configurable>Company_SaleableIndex_Configurable</product_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And the class I'm using:

```
<?php

class Company_SaleableIndex_Configurable extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable {

    public function isSalable($product = false)
    {
        die('asdf');
    }

}
```

The module itself seems to be working fine as I'm getting an error in the frontend as soon as I activate it. The Rewrite seems to be working also because if I remove it, no error gets thrown.

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function setConfig() on boolean in /var/www/sites/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php on line 80
```

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 on Apache.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_SaleableIndex>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_SaleableIndex>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <company_saleableIndex>
                <class>Company_SaleableIndex_Model</class>
            </company_saleableIndex>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_type_configurable>Company_SaleableIndex_Model_Configurable</product_type_configurable>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Then, create a php file name Configurable.php in Company/SaleableIndex/Model

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working as expected!
Care to explain WHY this is working? How do all those namespace etc. fit together? Especially `Company_SaleableIndex_Model ` which I have defined nowhere?

Comment: Magento structure is built in MVC model. And you are trying to customize a model file. So you need to initial a custom model file with magento system.